# Avoiding query in loop - specific case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, paypal

I'm in a position where I do not see a possibility to avoid a `SELECT` query inside a `for` loop, therefore I'm asking here.

**The situation is this:** I'm creating an e-commerce system and it implements the Paypal cart system. After an user pays, the IPN response looks something like this (shortened):

```
Array 
(
    [mc_gross] => 8.98
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [item_number1] => item_49
    [tax] => 0.00
    [item_number2] => item_16
    [num_cart_items] => 2
    [address_state] => CA
    [item_name1] => Tractor
    [item_name2] => Elegy
    [quantity1] => 1
    [quantity2] => 1
    [txn_type] => cart
    [mc_gross_1] => 5.99
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [mc_gross_2] => 2.99
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [payment_gross] => 8.98
)
```

As you see, there are some keys saying `somethingN`. This is where the trouble begins.

I use the `num_cart_items` as the number of iterations I have to do, like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['cart_num_items']; $i++)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Well obviously, now inside this loop, I'd be able to access each cart item that has `N` at the end of it. And what I need is to verify the sold products against fraud.

I have to select the price of the item number from `item_numberN` from **my database** and compare it against the price which was received from Paypal's response.

This select statement has to happen inside this loop, as far as I see.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not great at PHP, but couldn't you simply do a query in SQL like SELECT item_price FROM products WHERE id = item_number1 OR id = item_number2.... OR id = item_numberX, etc? That would at least give you one SQL query instead of having a massive for loop.

Comment: What if someone bought 120 items?

Comment: There's no reason it wouldn't work for 120 items. It's much more efficient than:

1) Opening connection to DB
2) Sending very small query
3) Waiting for response
4) Receiving data for small query
5) Close connection

x120 times

Comment: Please give me a demonstration with 120 cart items, I'd like to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the query in your for loop, you have to collect all `item_numbers` from the ipn response. Then, use these `item_numbers` to generate a query with an `IN` statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `item_number` IN ('item_49', 'item_16')
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reminder! This is what you get when you take breaks from programming.